# Addition using next object's property value in List

Tags: c#, list

I want to make addition using next object's property value in list. 
Here is the sample code.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<Model> modelList { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
       modelList = GetModelList(); 
    }
    public List<Model> GetModelList()
    {
        return new List<Model>
        {
            new Model(){Number = 1, Total = 0},
            new Model(){Number = 2, Total = 0},
            new Model(){Number = 3, Total = 0},
            new Model(){Number = 4, Total = 0},
        };
    }
}
public class Model
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

In above case :
`modelList[0].Total` should be `modelList[0].Number + modelList[1].Number`
What could be the best way to achieve this ? Any help ?

Below is the code How I am achieving currently

```
for (int i = 0; i < modelList.Count - 1; i++)
{
    modelList[i].Total = modelList[i].Number + modelList[i + 1].Number;
}
```

Comment: The best way (IMHO) is when your `Model` knows nothing about the `List` it's stored

Comment: what should be the result of the last computation?

Comment: @Daniel last object should be 0 as it is

Comment: I have updated question with my solution

Answer (score 1):

I added a method `ComputeTotal` to show a solution

```
public MyClass()
{
    modelList = GetModelList();
    modelList = ComputeTotal(modelList);
}

private List<Model> ComputeTotal(List<Model> models)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < models.Count; i++)
    {
        var hasNext = (i + 1) < models.Count;

        // no computation if hasNext is false
        if (hasNext)
        {
            var currentNumber = models[i].Number;
            var nextNumber = models[i + 1].Number;
            models[i].Total = currentNumber + nextNumber;
        }

    }

    return models;
}
```

i know this is very explicit. But it clearly demonstrates the approach.

[image]

Update:

added the `hasNext` check to avoid `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`

[image]

Comment: isn't this the same code, that is listed in question under _"Below is the code How I am achieving currently"_?

Comment: it is not. because the code you mentioned will throw `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. '`

Comment: why do you think so? It is running from `0` to `models.Count - 1`, just like yours. Except it doesn't do useless `hasNext` calculation on every turn.

Comment: He was updating his code after i provided the solution. The code sample from Dhruv is not complete. he needs to do the `hasNext`-check somewhere else

Comment: You don't get it. OP code is working too. Code from question is not throwing `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. Your `var hasNext = (i + 1) < models.Count` calculation is done on **each and every** iteration, more then that, it is useless if you move it to a precondition of `for`-loop. Just like in question: `for (int i = 0; i < modelList.Count - 1; i++)` and you don't need to calculate `hasNext` million times for a huge list. But if you move this check to a `for`-loop precondition, your code will be exactly the same, that is used by OP already.

Comment: @vasily.sib maybe i am not getting it. updated the answer with a screenshot if i leave out the check

Comment: replace your line: `for (var i = 0; i < models.Count; i++)` with this line: `for (var i = 0; i < modelList.Count - 1; i++)` and leave out the check

Comment: now i got it. Thanks for pointing out. As i said Dhruv posted 'How I am achieving currently' after the answer was written. So basically he solved it by hisself with or without my answer. Can't tell. We can ask him.